# Create Resource Icons Dll

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i want to create resource dll in Vb.net mean like SHELL32.Dll
i want to store my icons and pngs for my custom file extensions.
Thanks..........

Comment: You might consider simply storing these inside of your executable (.exe) instead of in a separate resource DLL. (Unless of course they need to be localizable—then ignore everything I just said.)

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported by the IDE.  These resources are not the kind that you're familiar with, they are unmanaged resources.  The VB.NET compiler does support the option, /win32resource, you'll however have to run it by hand.  You'll also need to run the rc.exe tool by hand to create the .res file.

Using VB.NET is just not the best way to get this done.  It is natively supported by the C++ IDE.

- File + New + Project
- Select Visual C++, Win32, Win32 Project
- Next, select DLL
- Right-click the Resource Files folder in the Solution Explorer window
- Add + Resource, Import and select the icon
- Repeat as necessary for every icon you want to add
- Build + Build.

You can use View + Other Windows + Resource View to edit the content.  One thing you almost certainly want to do is change the ID of the icon from a symbol to a number.  That's the number you'll use in the registry entry.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you create a new class library add all of the icons and then change the Resources class to have a public modifier?

EDIT: the resources class is public

The link below works for setting the association: (based on comment feedback)

http://mel-green.com/2009/04/c-set-file-type-association/

Comment: i already registered my file associations into registry so i want to set icons to my files how can i do that?...

Comment: ah ok, have you read these? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/fileicon.aspx    http://mel-green.com/2009/04/c-set-file-type-association/

Answer (score 0):

You have to create blank DLL project with just added icons to project (not resources).

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984332(v=vs.71).aspx

VentyCZ